# How to display full table when using PrinterJob in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, printing

I have table with only 3 rows and 5 columns, when printing it prints all 3 rows but only 3 columns. This is my code:

```
  private void print(Node node)        
  Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
  PageLayout pageLayout
    = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, 
  Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
  PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

    if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(node.getScene().getWindow())) {
        boolean success = job.printPage(node);
        if (success) {
            job.endJob();
        }
    }
```

This is button:

```
  printButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            print(tableView);
        }
    });
```

What should i do so i can see all columns? i'm using old hp laserjet professional p1102 printer.

Comment: For one thing, you can try changing PageOrientation.PORTRAIT to PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE.

Comment: @VGR Nothing has changed. Any other solution?

Comment: You are not actually doing anything with the PageLayout you created.  Pass it as the first argument to `job.printPage`.

Comment: @VGR Nope, but even if it was change, that's now what i want. I can print in landscape when i choose option in `showPrintDialog`. I need in a4 format

Comment: Okay, so you have a very wide table but you want to force it to fit on a portrait-oriented page.  Are you willing to scale the table down, when printing, to make it fit?

Comment: @VGR it's now wide table at all, it has only 5 columns with 4 digit number in them. Yes anything to put it on paper

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra what is the problem in my question? I think it's easy to understand

Comment: it's not reproducible without writing additional code ... which is your job :)

Comment: @kleopatra i only have button that calls print method,  thought that was obvious.

Comment: might be .. or not: to exclude the latter __you__ should write the boilerplate around the obvious ..

Answer (score 0):

[JavaFX8 Print API : how to set correctly the Printable area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231021/javafx8-print-api-how-to-set-correctly-the-printable-area/31232149#31232149) This is where i found answer. I only need to change height:

```
double scaleX
    = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth() / node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
double scaleY
    = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight() / node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
Scale scale = new Scale(scaleX, scaleY)//insted of scaleY i put number 1
```

So it will not stretch table height all over the paper.